# Why do I see this icon when I do not have any reviews

Tags: bug

I see this
[image]

When clicking the 5 icon it goes to the suggested edits page and shows no reviews.

What is happening here

Comment: Please see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/233535/review-counts-in-top-bar-and-review-dont-match

Comment: Possible duplicate of [False review count](http://meta.elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/170/false-review-count)

Answer (score 1):

There are still items in the queue—they are just not visible/available to you. More on how this works [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137074/dont-show-pending-suggested-edits-to-me-after-i-run-out-of-votes)